# concatenate text with records saved rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, concatenation, string-concatenation

hello for my app I need to save a record that the user type, for example if an user type in:

```
<p><%= f.label :fruit %><br />
<%= f.file_field :fruit%></p>

"apple"
```

in the show page I need that record appears like

```
"bag of "+ :fuit
```

, but I don't want to save "bag of", how can I put that text when the user is in the show page?? 
I have read something about the filters but I don't understand so much I'm pretty new in rails

if you need more info (like code) just tell me, thanks

**EDIT**
for now in my model I have this

```
before_save: add_bag

def add_bag
  self.fruit = ("bag of" + self.fruit)
end
```

but that save all this "bag of apple"

Comment: I have to add something to my controller??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you do something like this (assuming your model is Foo)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bag
    "bag of #{fruit}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.fruit = "apple"
puts foo.fruit # => "apple"
puts foo.bag   # => "bag of apple"
```

Is this what you want?